# Retrieved data from tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been breaking my head for 3 hours now and I can't figure this out, I recently started working with Rails and I'm in love with it, but there's still some little things I don't know. Like I have a view that pulls all the data from a table.

```
<% @albums.each do |album| %>
<div class="album">
<%= album.artist %> - <%= album.album %>
</div>

<div class="albumTask">
  <%= link_to 'Show', album %>
  <% if can? :update, @album %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_album_path(album) %>
  <% end %>
  <% if can? :destroy, @albumy %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', album, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

But what I really want it to do is to only pull the data where genre = Dubstep. Now in PHP I would do something like.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE genre='dubstep'")
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's important for you is understanding how the MVC (model-view-controller) architecture works. Here's a link [on how it works](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/).

The code you provided is your view, and it knows how to display a list of albums. But it's the controller that does most of the job in MVC, such as giving a list of albums to your view. Now currently, if it wants to index all the albums, it calls this part in your `/app/controllers/AlbumsController.rb`:

```
def index
  @albums = Album.all

  respond_to [...]
  [...]
end
```

This is where the `@albums.do each {...}` in your view comes from. What I would do is similar, but instead of `.all`, pass a `.where(:genre => :params[:genre])` clause instead, where the parameter comes from your url.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ActiveRecord, just add where clause to the query:

```
Album.where(:genre => "dubstep")
```

Some additional info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Album.find_all_by_genre("dubstep")
```